# No existing unique id for external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have anumber of external drives attaches to an old Mac Mini running Ubuntu 20.04. Doing an `lsblk` yields:

```
sda                         8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
|-sda1                      8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
|-sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
`-sda3                      8:3    0 464.3G  0 part
  `-ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   200G  0 lvm  /
sdb                         8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
sdc                         8:32   0   5.5T  0 disk
`-sdc1                      8:33   0   5.5T  0 part
sdd                         8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
`-sdd1                      8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
sde                         8:64   0   1.8T  0 disk
|-sde1                      8:65   0   200M  0 part
|-sde2                      8:66   0   1.8T  0 part
`-sde3                      8:67   0   128M  0 part
sdf                         8:80   0   3.7T  0 disk
`-sdf1                      8:81   0   3.7T  0 part
```

So far so good - the drive of interest is `/dev/sdf`. It can be manipulated and mounted just fine. However, I want an unique id for this drive - `ls -la /dev/disk/by-id`:

[snip]

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000000000000001 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000000000000001-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000cca23dd3be54 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000cca7b1c30b9a -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000cca7b1c30b9a-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000cca7b1c30b9a-part2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x5000cca7b1c30b9a-part3 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x50014ee2573d34a7 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   10 Aug 11 11:32 wwn-0x50014ee2573d34a7-part1 -> ../../sdd1
```

As can be seen, all the drives are present except `/dev/sdf`. The same goes for `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and everything else.

The drive is connected to the computer by a FireWire 800 daisy-chain, although I don't see how this should affect it.

EDIT: I connected the drive using its USB 2.0 interface, and now it works properly. Using USB 2.0 is not an optiuon though, so is there anything else I could try wrt. the FireWire interface?

Comment: this SU Q/A might help understand the problem: https://superuser.com/questions/839667/how-is-by-id-created-on-linux . If there's no equivalent information either available or used with the firewire interface, then nothing would be populated. Is there anything with MINOR=8 MAJOR=80 available with `udevadm info --export-db` ? Also (still reading at the answers) do you have a file in  /lib/udev/rules.d/ dealing with firewire? eg: https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/-/blob/debian/buster/rules/60-persistent-storage.rules#L60 . Hope this helps you check further

Comment: Thanks. Knowing now what to look for I can see some other FireWire drives that I have pop up as ieee1394-{} under /dev/disk/by-id. So, I am starting to wonder if this drive is somehow failing when used through its FW interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the WWN of the disk `sdc` might not actually globally unique, as it is supposed to be.

When the missing drive reappeared, did some other drive vanish from the `/dev/disk/by-*` directories in turn?

If so, you may have a duplicate ID, and when there are overlapping IDs, the most recently added disk may "win". That might explain why the USB connection apparently made it work.

If you actually have two disks with identical WWNs, and their contents were clones of each other at some point of their history, that might explain what you're seeing.

Changing the WWN might not be possible, but if you could assign new, unique UUIDs to the partition table and filesystem(s) of one of the conflicting pair, that might at least minimize the problems caused.

A recent enough version of `fdisk` should have a function that allows you to regenerate random UUIDs for partitions, if I recall correctly (I'm on mobile, will edit later). For filesystem UUIDs, filesystem-type-specific tools like `tune2fs` tend to have a similar feature.

Comment: As mentioned above I have now tried other FW drives. None of them show up under the "wwn-{}" id, but instead as ieee1394-{}. As for the theory about global uniqueness, I tried the drive with all other drives disconnected, but to no avail. I also used mkfs.ext4 to format the drive and used the UUID provided to mount the drive through fstab. This worked, but after a reboot the drive was not bootable again.I am starting to suspect a subtly failing drive here.